# How to set the configuration of mini-css-extract-plugin in vue.config.js generated by vue-cli

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli, mini-css-extract-plugin

I have a fairly large Vue project that was initially created with vue-cli. I'm getting the infamous "couldn't fulfill desired order of chunk group(s)" warning when building. After much searching, I think the solution is to add `ignoreOrder` to the initial configuration options for `mini-css-extract-plugin` but I have no idea how. I think this should be done in `vue.config.js`. The contents of that file are:

```
module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: false
}
```

I've tried:

```
module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: false,
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ ignoreOrder: true })
    ]
  }
}
```

But that gives me an error that I think means that the module was loaded twice.

I've tried:

```
module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: false,
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      ignoreOrder: true
    }
  }
}
```

but that gives me a syntax error.

How do I set that option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [document](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#css-extract), you can pass the configuration for [`min-css-extract-plugin`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin) by passing the options via `css.extract` property as following:

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...,
  css: {
    extract: {
      ignoreOrder: true
    },
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you! I was looking at that page but didn't associate the keyword "extract" with that plugin.